# System becomes unresponsive when my kernel module tries to access task->mm->pgd

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to print the value of `tsk->mm->pgd` for all tasks (`task_struct`). I have a branch to judge if the `mm` or `pgd` is `NULL`. But, if the program access the value of `pgd`, I can't control the system. The operating system becomes unresponsive.

The following `testFunc` is defined in a kernel module:

```
void testFunc(void)
{
    struct task_struct *p=&init_task;

    printk(KERN_INFO "testFunc\n");

    pid_t pid = current->pid;
    printk(KERN_INFO "current PID - %d, - pgd %px\n", pid, current->mm->pgd);

    for_each_process(p)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "pid - %d\tpname - %s\n", p->pid, p->comm);
        if(p->mm && p->mm->pgd)
            printk(KERN_INFO "%px\n", p->mm->pgd);
    }
}
```

I want to know why this happens.

And is there any method to make it work?

Comment: Well, for one, you are not taking any lock of any kind, so both the task and the mm you are working with could vanish at any moment and you'd be operating on invalid/dangling pointers...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Finally, I found that the reason is that the mm pointer of the kernel process is NULL. But your opinion can make the code more safe and robust. I will go to learn more about locks in kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you are not taking any lock of any kind, so both the task and the mm you are working with could vanish at any moment and you'd be operating on invalid/dangling pointers.

To avoid this, there are different lock/unlock pairs of functions protecting different parts of `task_struct` that you can use. The following code should be what you are looking for:

```c
#include <linux/sched/task.h>   // struct task_struct, {get,put}_task_struct()
#include <linux/sched/signal.h> // for_each_process()
#include <linux/sched/mm.h>     // get_task_mm(), mmput()
#include <linux/mm.h>

/* ... */

void testFunc(void)
{
    char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
    struct task_struct *p;
    struct mm_struct *mm;

    for_each_process(p) {
        get_task_struct(p);
        get_task_comm(comm, p);
        mm = get_task_mm(p);

        if (mm) {
            pr_info("PID %d (\"%s\") pgd = %px\n", p->pid, comm, mm->pgd);
            mmput(mm);
        } else {
            pr_info("PID %d (\"%s\") is an anonymous process\n", p->pid, comm);
        }

        put_task_struct(p);
    }
}
```

See also [this Linux kernel documentation page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/active_mm.rst) explaining the difference between `task->mm` and `task->active_mm`, and what it means for a task to have `task->mm == NULL`.